# How to properly model interest accumulation in an event sourced savings account application?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

In my event sourced application developed using DDD, there are saving accounts that should accumulate interest every day. At the end of every year the accumulated interest should be capitalized. My question is: **Should every daily calculation really be treated as a domain event?**

An alternative could be to calculate the accumulated interest at a given point in time on the **read side** by traversing the transactions that has happened on the account up until that day (withdrawals, deposits etc), and sum the accumulated interest for each day.

The amount of events in the event store would quickly grow to millions, given that there could be hundreds of thousands saving accounts in the system calculating their accumulated interest each day. But at the same time it seems like a drawback to have to calculate the accumulated interest "on the fly" on the read side instead of raising an event every day.

Comment: I'm no banking expert, but *InterestCredited* looks like the event you really want to store since it will change the state of the system. Accumulated interest is a virtual concept if I understand correctly - modelling it as an event of its own adds no value. A simple read-side value recalculated each day seems to match the need pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I talked to my colleagues and they had similar opinions. Thinking about it as a virtual concept really helped me understand the problem. I will create an application serivce that can calculate the accumulated interest given a certain point in time.

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer. Maybe wait a little for other answers to come - again, I'm no banking specialist and it would be interesting to have the PoV of an expert in the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no banking expert, but `InterestCredited` looks like the event you really want to store since it will change the state of the system.

*Accumulated interest* is a virtual concept if I understand correctly - modelling it as an event of its own adds no value. You would be able to calculate the capitalized interest at the end of the year anyways regardless of daily `InterestAccumulated` events being present. Instead, a simple read-side value recalculated each day seems to match the need pretty well.

Comment: What he said, plus that you want to have a read persistence model storing the relevant data (from the event), then a query object which will do the actual calculation. If you extract an interface from that query object, you can use it as a domain service.

Comment: @MikeSW "storing the relevant data (from the event)" Well... I though this answer said not to have any InterestAccumulated event at all so I'm wondering how you will be doing this. Also, what do you mean by a query object? What would the implementation look like? I was thinking that for simple interest calculations a projection would do the trick. However, interest earning can be very complex at it's worst so I guess that running that logic in the domain model would be best in those cases.

Comment: I'm thinking about only storing the actual transactions (deposits, withdrawals, capitalizations...) as events, and based on that information the read side can calculate the daily interest by using a domain service to execute the actual interest calculation formula and passing in balance and interest rate for any given day.

Answer (score 2):

Interest accumulation is only a domain event when it gets credited/debited to an account. Until that occurs it doesn't mutate aggregate state. Consider corrective events, posting errors (e.g an NSF credit reversal). You would need to correct for every daily incorrect interest calculation between the original and correction.

The read side can take care of rolling up accrued interest at whatever intervals desired.

Comment: Indeed, not counting each and every accumulation as an event on its own has given me a lot of advantages. For example it is easier to do corrections and registering late transactions now, without making all the "InterestAccumulated" events deprecated. It is still important though, to keep domain specific operations such as the interest formula in a separate application service to not spill logic to the read side.

Comment: You are correct on the interest calculation. It would have been better to suggest _displaying_ the current accrued interest on the read side. It all depends on the requirements. If the accrued interest is only informational on the read side precision & accuracy may not be guaranteed until it's posted to the account.

Answer (score 1):

> Should every daily calculation really be treated as a domain event?

What do your domain experts say?

You might also want to review chapter 11 of [the blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), which includes "Example: Earning Interest with Accounts".  That may not directly answer your question about the domain events, but it should provide you with some extra context for framing your own analysis.

I'm not a domain expert, but my expectation would be that accrued interest has implications, either legal, or in the model, and that you would expect to have a consistent record of the accrual and *its consequences on your model*.

From your initial description, the impact on the model is annual, so I would expect to see the InterestCapitalized event only once per year per account.  But I find it difficult to believe that daily accrued interest doesn't matter, especially in the face of changing balances and compounding interest, so I'm suspicious that the described requirement actually matches the needs of the business.

I wouldn't expect "millions" of events to be that big a problem; using the CQRS pattern, most of your reads are going to come out of rolled up results anyway, so that's not a big deal.  The real hurt will be in trying to re-hydrate an aggregate with millions of events; but if you are facing performance problems there, you can look into loading the aggregate from snapshots.

And of course, if each account is calculating its own accrued interest, then you are only looking at 365 (ish) extra events per year, which is no sweat at all.

Comment: Compund interest isn't applied until the interest has been capitalized at the end of the year. So the daily accumulated amount wouldn't have to be used in any calculations except at the end of the year anyways. And yes, every account is calculating its own interest. I really wouldn't like performance issues to hinder me from designing the model correctly, but as far as i can tell from answers and co-workers, daily interest calculation isn't really a domain event.